# More Tab icons colour in iOS 8 and later

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

**Background:**
I am working on an application with multiple tabs, so there is a more tab on the right.

**Issue:**
In iOS 7, the colour of icons in more tab was **grey**, which is Apple's default.
But from iOS 8 and later, the colour of those icons are changed to **blue**.

**Expected:**
I want the icons colour in the more tab to be **grey**.

I have tried multiple solutions related to UITabBar icon's images, but no one worked.
I have attached the images for both iOS7 and iOS8-and-later. [image: more-tab-iOS7] [image: more-tab-iOS8-and-later]

Comment: Please add code how you are setting image for tab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your application's global tint color. If you are using Storyboards, this option is available in the Documents section of the File Inspector.

According to Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html), "If you don’t specify a tint for the window, it uses the system default color."

Comment: Thanks mate, it helped!
I used the following line of code to set the application's global tint color:
[self.window setTintColor:color_tint];